# Ratio of areas of objects, when areas cannot be calculated directly but random draws are available

Tags: geometry, statistics

I have two geometric objects, $O_{1}$ and $O_{2}$, of which $O_{2}$ lies completely in $O_{1}$. Let's assume $O_{1}$ is a circle and $O_{2}$ is a smaller circle. I need to know the ratio of the areas of both objects, however, I cannot calculate the areas of the objects directly and I cannot draw uniformly distributed points from the objects either.

However, I have a set of points $x_{i=1,...,n}$ drawn from the same distribution $p(x_{i})$ of which some $x_{i=1,...,c}$ lie in $O_{2}$ and respectively more of these points $x_{i=1,...,d}$ (where $d>c$) lie in $O_{1}$. Some points $x_{i=d+1,...,n}$ lie outside both objects. I do not know the distribution from which these points were drawn, but I know a function $f(x_{i})$ that is proportional to the distribution these points were drawn from (i.e. its density), such that $f(x_{i}) \propto p(x_{i})$.

How can I use the available information to find the ratio of the areas of these two objects? I am not clever enough to construct the right weights $w_{i}$ to obtain the correct ratio $\frac{\sum^{c}_{i=1}(w_{i})}{\sum^{d}_{i=1}(w_{i})}$.

Thanks for any hint!!!

Comment: Essential: make requests with keyword "stereology"

Answer (score 1):

The classic Monte Carlo solution assumes the distribution is uniform over all the points that lie in $O_1$ and perhaps some that lie outside $O_1$.  In that case you just take the ratio of the number of points in $O_2$ to the number of points in $O_1$ and are done.

If you have an unknown distribution of the probabilities of picking the points there is no answer.  Consider one distribution where the probability of picking points in $O_2$ was nonzero and the the probability of picking points outside $O_2$ was zero.  Every point picked would be in both, so you would claim the areas are equal.  Consider a second distribution where every point picked is outside $O_2$ but inside $O_1$.  You would conclude the area of $O_2$ is zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RossMillikan your example is very conclusive. However, there should be a (set of) conditions for the original distribution $p(x_{i})$ making the result $\frac{\sum^{c}_{i=1}(1/f(x_{i})}{\sum^{d}_{i=1}(1/f(x_{i}))}$ since $f(x_{i}) = c p(x_{i})$, right? Like the condition that $p(x_{i})$ explores $O_{1}$ and $O_{2}$ well?

Comment: If you know the distribution but it is uneven you can still compute it by weighting the points with their inverse probabilities, but you said the distribution was unknown.